# Should we change the accept-answer feature to question-solved?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Do we really gain something by the possibility of accepting an answer? (**Edit 2**: following the interesting points remarked by other users, the question should probably be *Shouldn't we replace the accept-answer feature by a simple question-solved feature that doesn't highlight any particular reply?*) I can find reasons against the former feature and I struggle thinking of the advantages compared to the simply question-solved attribute.

A false answer can be chosen as accepted—it doesn't happen often, but by design it can—, and sometimes I've seen the most accurate or complete answer not being the one accepted. As such one wonders: what is the point of this?

If the goal of Stack Exchange is to create fora where individuals can find correct answers to pertinent questions, the value of a reply should much more depend on its support by the community—by being upvoted—than by its acceptance by someone who, by the mere fact of asking the question, is not in the best position to choose whether the answer is appropriate or not.

I can see that an advantage of this feature lies in the fact that, by accepting an answer, the subject is considered closed. However, because of the above and how misleading can be the notion of "accepted answer"—particularly when this answer moves to the top, shadowing the other, perhaps better answers—, shouldn't this feature change? Perhaps it would be more appropriate to let the person asking the question choose whether his/her doubts have been solved, without him/her specifying a reply.

As it has been pointed out in other threads, another reason for this feature to exist is to reward the person that gave the accepted answer. Again, though, isn't this detrimental for the quality of the answers? Someone shouldn't be rewarded by giving a satisfying answer, but by giving a good one. What makes a good answer is indeed subjective, and hence up to the community, but rewarding for "accepted answers" doesn't promote good answers any more than rewarding for being upvoted does and, contrarily, since it's a one-person decision it promotes answers that might not be the best.

**Edit 2**: On the other hand it has been noted that one of the points of accepting an answer is *letting the person answering know* that you have read and been helped by his/her reply. Now in this sense, again the accept-answer feature is improvable: if I ask a question I generally read and find useful multiple of the answers; should I then be able to accept multiple answers? I might even wanna give "special thanks" to more than one user, which would imply in this sense accepting multiple answers.

All in all, I have the impression the problems of accepting an answer could be solved by marking questions as solved and notifying people their answer has been upvoted by the OP. I see, however, by the feedback of other users this opinion is unpopular. I will not delete the post, though, because I want to let other people comment on this if they want to.

---

**Edit 1**: some have noted that no, you do not *have* to accept an answer; indifferently of this fact—which is not fully true, because the site itself incites the user to choose an answer—the points I stated above are independent of the fact the acceptance of an answer is mandatory or optional.

**Edit 3**: w.r.t. to a point in Tetsujins's answer, I agree: any feature or mechanism demands learning to read the clues. Nevertheless, I have the impression that my suggestions would make things easier to grasp by new-comers or external users landing here through a web search.

Comment: ...You don't _have_ to accept an answer.

Comment: _"let the person asking the question choose whether his/her doubts have been solved"_ That's what accepting an answer does!

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project) - attempts have been made to try to reduce the influence of answer acceptance on SO.

Comment: No, @CDR, accepting an answer does more than simply signaling a post as not needing more replies.

Comment: People that keep upvoting the first comment seem to neglect my edition.

Comment: (If you want to use a Latin word form, the correct plural of _forum_ is _fora.)_

Comment: It does more than just mark it as resolved, yes, but one of its impacts is just that. Your reply to my second comment seems to misinterpret it.

Comment: @tripleee - it hurt my OCD so much I fixed it, long before I got to your comment. I anglicised too; forums is fine (I also noted in the edit summary that "Stack Exchange is not a forum"™ ;)

Comment: @CDR, unless I am getting you wrong, I think you are missing my whole point: I know one of its impacts its just that, I say it myself in the question. What I note is that this effect could be achieved with a feature that ONLY does that, namely signaling the question doesn't need more replies, without highlighting a specific answer---and hence avoiding the vices related to this feature---.

Comment: I see. Your title reads more like one for discussion, consider changing it to one more reflective of your post's nature. Perhaps something along the lines of  _'Give users a way to mark their question as resolved without accepting an answer'_ would be more descriptive. (Just a suggestion.)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. But please don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers.

Answer (score 6):

For users who might be able to answer the question (which they could see from the tags and/or title), an accepted answer means they can perhaps move on to the next question, since their immediate assistance is not needed.

For users with the same question: with an accepted answer, you can be reasonably sure that it worked for at least one person. Sure, an answer with a decent score may indicate that as well, but users can also upvote without trying or really understanding the answer, just because it's written by a high-reputation user, because it has a high score so it must be good. Or, even though it's a bad answer, because it has impeccable grammar and style because the author <s>generated it with AI</s> is a good writer. Those are bad reasons to upvote, but it happens (I guess it's part of human nature, and I'm guilty as well).

Comment: Thank you for replying with something else than "you don't need to accept an answer". As I mentioned above, I was already aware of your first point. Nevertheless I did not thought of your last point, namely that upvoting doesn't only mean "this is the correct answer", which indeed is a good one.

Comment: « it's written by a high-reputation user». This is not a reason to upvote. It is unfair, incorrect, user-based voting, and harms the site.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship i mean. that doesn't change the fact that people do it. This answer isn't suggesting it's a good practice.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship I completely agree, I hope the edit makes things clearer?

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, definitely. It's fine to point out these reasons, because they are real, but they should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

For any arena where there exists a competitive element, there will always be some areas where the 'result' as judged by a limited sample set audience does not conform to the overall majority view.

…which is jargonese for "You win some, you lose some" or "You can't have it all ways."

If it's *my* answer I want to see that the OP was at least engaged sufficiently to return & mark it accepted. [This actually has nothing to do with reputation points; on most of the sites I regularly engage in, I have points a-plenty. They are no drive to me any more.]
That's fine if my answer was 'perfect'. Time may prove it wasn't.

If I come upon a question I had no prior involvement in, especially one not in its first flush of youth, I will scan all answers. If there is a hint of the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) then that's likely to be balanced by the next answer down having a far greater score. If I have sufficient privileges on that site, I'll also check the up/downvote balance.

There could be a better system, sure, but better minds than mine have tried to come up with one and not changed the way the world spins.
First past the post can often out-haul all other following answers for upvotes, especially if the question hits HNQ, because 'sheep syndrome'. …but HNQ brings users to areas they may not have otherwise looked at. Someone may need to provide lengthy stats & equations to prove or disprove whether that's *'a good thing'*.

I think as it stands, you just have to learn to read the clues.

If I personally could change anything in how acceptance works, I'd like to be able to 'unaccept' my own answer & be able to delete it, if I know a far better answer has come along later. Maybe that would have to be a high rep privilege, to mitigate abuse or rage-quit.